# Wrong display when adding radio group into ribbon page?

Tags: c#, devexpress, ribbon

I'm facing up to a problem when using DevExpress Ribbon Control

I need to add a radio button group with two options such as "First", "Second" into ribbon page, but it only shows ***[ ] F [ ] S*** instead of ***[ ] First [ ] Second***

How can I fix it?

In addition, I need group display in vertical or horizontal as an option, but I can't find anywhere to do that.

Hope to be help. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally find how to set radio button group as I expected.

Just modify `ItemHeight`, `Column`, and `Width` property to do that!